# Not Able to start a session on a hosting server

Tags: php, html, session, authentication

I checked all the other possible duplicates before posting but none of them solved my problem
Everything was working perfectly fine when using localhost, now i'm trying to upload it on a host server, but there seem to be a problem when i try to start a session..
This is the part of code concerned:

```
header('refresh:5;URL= ./info.php');
print "<br/>Signed in Successfully<br /> You will be redirected shortly";
session_start();
$_SESSION["login_user"]=$_POST["inputUsername"];
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

And this is the corresponding output:
[image]
As you can see from the code, After the session was started, The word "Started" should be printed, which is not the case, However the print statement just before the session_start was executed.
Any idea what could be the problem?
Thank you

Comment: please... this -> print "<br />SignUp Successfull"; is != from Signed in Successfully

Comment: Oh Placed the differend part of code here, my bad. However same problem persists for both

Comment: we need the real code OP the help you

Comment: if you got an if before your code (after edit) than really check if is entering that. You can create a php script with session_start, $_SESSION['test'] = 'X'; and print $_SESSION['test']; to test the sessions =)

Comment: I have an if before the redirecting using header, but since The print statement just before the session_start is executed, i can safely assume that it is entering it.

Comment: try that page i was talking about to test sessions on your web server enviroment

Comment: ok i've just tried it and it works! And I was able to locate the error, it is in the header statement, because it worked perfectly fine when i tried to redirect to index.html instead of info.php .. Any idea what could be the problem there?

Comment: i normally put the session_start as the first element of my pages. That's maybe because it can't start sessions if we already got an header? Unknow, try putting up the session_start and maybe it solve

Answer (score 1):

You should always start your session first thing. Starting your session needs to send a header, which does not work if you've allready send one (for instance, explicitly, but also implicitly by e.g. doing output.

Always do your `session_start()` first.